# Error Exception: Service Spreadsheet failed while accessing document with id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, document

I could not find the solution to this error in the previous answers. I'm running this script under Google Apps Scripts with Google Sheets. So I would like you to review my simple line of code to see if there is something I overlooked:

`var firstCSV = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://drive.google.com/file/d/14EA51XsRpohpFVCwpO3sZwf_H3o6Dp_o/edit#gid=0");`

Error on this line -

`Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 14EA51XsRpohpFVCwpO3sZwf_H3o6Dp_o.   GregReport    @ Receipts Calculator.gs:37`

- I first tried using "openById" using just the ID number and got the
  same error message.
- Next I tried using the "openByUrl" using the document's URL and got
  the same error message.
- I checked the file on Google drive and it's there and I can open it.
- I ran this line of code in a script by itself and got the same error.
- I changed the URL in the code to a Sheets document URL an I got the
  same error.
- The original file has a .csv extension but my understanding is this
  should work just fine in Sheets.
- With both document formats and different methods I'm getting this
  same error.
- Any suggestions, or code updates I'm not aware would be appreciated.
  All I'm trying to do is open a spreadsheet and extract some data from
  it using a script built in Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to directly call a CSV file as a spreadsheet in Apps Script whether by using the file ID or the drive url.

What you need to do is to parse the CSV and get the content of it and paste it into a spreadsheet in Apps Script. Please see sample code below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(your-filename-here).next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1,csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData)
}
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful to find out that this is a system limitation. I hope the developers will consider adding the ability to call and work with CSV files and a few more formats in the future. JUST one more question, The CSV data was already parsed and put into rolls and columns using Exel but the file extension still is .csv. If that file extension was excel would my script be able call it then? If your answer is yes, how would you write a scrip line to just convert the file extension from .csv to .xlsx

Comment: Unfortunately, even if it is an xlsx file, Apps Script won't still be able to read it directly. You will still need to do similar approach to the one I did with my answer. Apparently, there is an article about converting xlsx files to google spreadsheet. Maybe you can explore on how it will make things easier for you. You can refer to this link -> https://www.labnol.org/code/20500-convert-microsoft-excel-xlsx-to-google-spreadsheet

Comment: If this answer helped you with your concern, please do accept/upvote so others will know how to deal with the same problem if they encounter it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. My Formula was about saving records from Sheet1 to sheet2. However, part of the range in sheet1 (The range which I use to get the last row) was an array formula. I kept getting the error until I change the Last row reference to another column that has no array formula. it could be the reason on your side.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31502150)